# Tate-Shafarevich group and Hasse principle

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I' m looking for a proof of the fact that the Hasse local-global principle holds for every **homogeneous space of elliptic curve $E $** defined over $\Bbb Q$ if and only if the Tate-Shafarevich group of $E$ is trivial.

I'm wondering why 山（E/$\Bbb Q$）is characterized as the group of everywhere local trivial homogeneous space for $\Bbb Q$.

Any referrences (webpage, book, etc...) are also appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Chapter X, Remark 4.1.2 combined with Proposition 3.3 of the same chapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for critical informations.How can we show  山（E/Q）is characterized as the group of everywhere local trivial homogeneous space for E/Q（Rem4.2）?. I'm looking for this proof.

Comment: Your initial statement is an if, but not only if. There are homogeneous spaces where the local-global principle holds even though the Tate-Shafarevich group is nontrivial (e.g., the elliptic curve $E$ itself). See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162089/tate-shafarevich-groups-and-hasse-principle-reference/1168492#1168492).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tate-Shafarevich groups and Hasse principle (reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162089/tate-shafarevich-groups-and-hasse-principle-reference)

Comment: No,I meant   ' every ’homogeneous space of E holds Hasse principle if and only if 山（E） is trivial. If you substitute 'every' to 'there exists',the statement automatically holds because as you pointed out, E is homogeneous space which holds the principle.

Comment: Then say "every", not "an" homogeneous space.

Comment: Thank you, I edited.