# Jacobian variety and Tate-Shafarevich group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves

It is known that if the Tate-Shafarevich group of an elliptic curve is trivial, then Hasse local-global principle holds for every homogeneuos space over the elliptic curve. I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162089/tate-shafarevich-groups-and-hasse-principle-reference) and [here](https://algant.eu/documents/theses/aka.pdf) (at 2.2.3 page 24), that we can get additional information by the Tate-Shafarevich group of the jacobian variety of the elliptic curve. More specifically, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162089/tate-shafarevich-groups-and-hasse-principle-reference) Brandon Carter says that "Hasse principle holds for a genus one curve $C$ defined over $\Bbb{Q}$ if and only if $C$ represents the trivial class in the Tate-Shafarevich group of its Jacobian" and then says "To get the precise statement I mentioned above, it is enough to read Chapter X, Sections 3 and 4 of Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves book."

But Silverman mentions the Tate-Shafarevich group of the Jacobian exectly 0 times (I've already read sections 3 and 4 in chapter X).

Where can I find a reference to Brandon Carter's statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SIlverman uses the notation $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$ for the Jacobian of $C$. Look just above Theorem 3.8 of X.3 (p 329 in my edition)

Comment: See in particular exercise 10.3 and Theorem 3.8. The point is that a genus $1$ curve $C$ is a homogeneous space for its Jacobian. So assume that $C(K_v) \ne \emptyset$ fall all $v$. Then, by definition, $C$ fails the Hasse principle if and only if $C(K)= \emptyset$. But by the definition of the TS group in terms of homogeneous spaces, $C$ gives an element of the TS group of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$. If this element is non-trivial, that exactly means that $C(K_v)\ne\emptyset$ for all $v$, but $C(K) = \emptyset$, i.e. $C$ fails the Hasse prinicple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!!

Comment: @Mathmo123 But why is TS group is trivial over $\Bbb{Q}$ (equivalent to- Hasse principle holds for any elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$)? As Brandon Carter mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Can you clarify your last question?

Comment: Brandon states that the Hasse principle holds for any elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$. Is it related to TS group or is it an additional claim?

Comment: Say that a curve $C$ violates the Hasse principle if $C(K_v)\ne \emptyset$ for all $v$, but $C(K) = \emptyset$. Then, trivially, any elliptic curve does not violate the Hasse principle, because, by definition, an elliptic curve has a rational point

Comment: The point of Brandon's answer is to give a criterion for $C$ to violate the Hasse principle if it has genus $1$. Let $E = \mathrm{Jac}(C)$. Then $C$ is a homogenous space for $E$, so it gives an element of the TS group of $E$. The criterion is that $C$ violates the Hasse principle if and only if the corresponding element of Sha is non-zero.

Comment: In particular, if the TS group of $E = \mathrm{Jac}(C)$ is trivial, then $C$ cannot violate the Hasse principle, but this condition is not necessary. For example, by definition, if $C$ was already an elliptic curve, then the corresponding element of Sha will be zero, whether or not Sha itself is zero.